# Oracle: How to do index range scan skipping a sub key's range?

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle 12c.

Consider a table names GRID_CELLS which stores a 100,000 x 100,000 grid cell data. The columns are as follows:

- X number
- Y number
- CELL_VALUE number

The index is consists of (X, Y), which is the primary key.

Since it's the grid cell data, nearly all the 'cell' has a record.

If the query is like this:

```
select * from GRID_CELLS where X >= 100 and X <= 200 and Y >= 100 and Y <= 200
```

Oracle will choose the index range scan, and will act as follows:

1. Traverse the B-tree index from the root node to find the first leaf node
2. Scan the leaf nodes all the way though the last leaf node accessing the table rows by rowid

That is, Oracle reads the leaf nodes for about 100,000 * 100 records, which would be a lot slower than the following (hypothetical) action.

1. Traverse the B-tree index from root to find the first leaf node for (>=100, >=100)
2. Scan the leaf nodes until it finds the record that has Y value greater than 200
3. Stop the leaf node scanning and re-traverse the B-tree index from the root node for the next X
4. Repeat 2 and 3

Can Oracle act like this? And if so, how can it be forced to do that? Or is there another optimal solution?

BTW, we cannot use partitioning. So, partitioning is not a solution.

**UPDATE**

I've tested the 2-bitmap-index configuration according to my comment below. The result is positive. It's 5 ~ 10 times faster than the B-tree index range scan.

But still it would be nice if Oracle skip leaf nodes while range-scanning B-tree index.

Comment: Is this a DSS application?  Or are there OLTP transactions on the table?

Comment: @JustinCave This is a data warehouse application. So no OLTP transactions.

Comment: If the table contains only 3 columns, and 2 of them are in the primary key, then the table can be coverted to an index organized table.Another option is the star transformation: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/star_transformation with X and Y as two dimensions tables and VALUE as a fact table.

Comment: @kordirko Perhaps two bitmap indexes, one for X, one for Y are the solution?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. SInce this is rather OLAP than OLTP system, two bitmap indexes on X and on Y will be a good choice.

Comment: @kordirko Thank you. I'll try it when time and resource permits.

Comment: What kind of query will you use? i mean it can be efficient to use **linear** address of a cell. It depends on sort of typical query and volatility of the grid size.

Comment: @agent5566 Since the grid is related to the geospatial data, I must use 2-dimensional address of a cell. I can use SDO_FILTER() to select the cells, but it seems overkill since the filter is only a rectangle, and the geometry type column is in the other table (so I must join with that table).

Comment: @kordirko I've tested 2-bitmap-index configuraiton. Please see my update.

Comment: @zeodtr It might help to include data about the size and time of the operations, for comparison.  I've tried to reproduce this environment at 1/4th scale (50K x 50K, for 2.5B rows).  This lead to a GRID_CELLS table with a segment size of 51GB, B-tree index size of 55GB, and bitmap index sizes 8GB and 0.6GB.  A query with full table scan took about 420 seconds, with B-Tree about 4 seconds, and bitmap was about 2 seconds.  Are your numbers drastically different than mine (after multiplying by 4 for the size difference)?

Comment: @JonHeller Sorry I didn't show the exact numbers. In my actual case, the property of the table is as follows: The grid is 28000 x 28000. 2. The grid cells are not 100% filled. The table has about 50 columns. (That is, a cell has many information). The table is partitioned by date. So the actual result can be different.

Comment: Index skip scanning can be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap indexes are one way to go. Even the star transformation is optimal when bitmap indexes are used. The problem with bitmap indexes is that they are large and slower to query when you have many different values for X and Y. They are best when you have small total number of different X and Y values present in table compared to number of rows.

---

There are some additional steps which can speed up the query:

You can partition the table by X or Y or both. Speed gain in this case depends on distribution of X and Y values and if your query selects a range of values.

You can make a functional index on X and Y or concatenate X and Y into a string and then create index on that string. Then you will have only one key. This might be the best solution because it decreases execution complexity by one degree.

Converting this table to IOT (index organized table) will give you benefits if disk I/O during execution is high, but that is usually the case with tables with many columns.

---

You have to always keep in mind the read/write ratio this table will have in production environment when deciding on indexing strategy. If there's high read count (SELECT) and low write count (INSERT) then you need to put most of the processing to write part: partition the table, create functional indexes, etc. If there's high write count and low read count and SELECT speed is not that important then one index on X and Y is the best solution.